# « Et quel russe n'aime pas la vitesse ? »

Tags: traduction, littérature, russe

Je cherche à rendre en français la phrase russe « *И какой же русский не любит быстрой езды*? », littéralement traduite par « Et quel russe n'aime pas la vitesse ? »

La phrase provient de l'œuvre *Les Âmes mortes* de Nicolaï Gogol, du chapitre où il parle très poétiquement de la « troïka » (le chariot russe). La phrase n'est qu'une question rhétorique,  à laquelle la réponse est évidente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telle quelle, la traduction convient, et serait peut-être idéale; bien sûr des variantes peuvent être trouvées.

- Et quel russe n'est pas fou de vitesse ? (*un petit peu plus fort*)
- Et [y a-t-il/existe-t-il] un russe que la vitesse ne grise pas ? (*plus littéraire*)

Comment: Merci, je pense que la première traduction ajoute la nuance, qui m'a manqué